# undefined timestamp of a file locked by a process

Tags: linux, unix, ls, stat

A daemon script creates some intermediate files which it removes at the end before sleeping. While the daemon script writes to the intermediate files, if we do an ls -lrt in the path we can see as follows:

:~/reports/jobs/Processorlog 12 $ ls -lrt|head

total 1276875

**?--------- ? ?      ?           ?            ? 48_QUERY1_1.log_spool.txt

?--------- ? ?      ?           ?            ? 48_QUERY1_1.log_opsspool.txt**

-rw-rw-r-- 1 jsil isdev 3703039 Jul 19 00:00 49_QUERY1_1-2013-07-18.log

-rw-rw-r-- 1 jsil isdev  856744 Jul 19 00:00 43_QUERY1-2013-07-18.log

The first 2 are the intermediate files which are locked by the daemon process and on doing ls -lrt it is showing ? timestamp.

Has anyone found this problem ?
And if we do a unix stat command on the file, what will the modification date of the file ?

Comment: Have you tried running `stat` on the file? Why ask us? (also, I'm guessing the files vanished while `ls` was looking at them, hence the output)

Comment: These files are also removed by the daemon script itself before sleeping, so I could not stat on the file. But as you said, looks like the files vanished while ls was looking at them. Any idea on how we could simulate the scenario ? Thanks for answering.

Comment: Not with `ls` specifically, but the sequence of events is roughly `d=opendir()`... `unlink(somefile)` ... `readdir(d)`...`fstat(somefile)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `ls` failed to `fstat` the files (presumably because they were removed before it got to them, but after being listed).